# Subclassing a singleton not working as expected

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, nsobject

I'm writing a class that communicates with an API. I started by creating a `SessionManager`:

```
@interface SessionManager : AFHTTPSessionManager

+ (id)sharedManager;

@end

static NSString *const kBaseURL = @"https://myapi.com";

@implementation SessionManager

- (id)init {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kBaseURL]];
    if(!self) return nil;

    self.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    self.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    return self;
}

+ (id)sharedManager {
    static SessionManager *_sessionManager = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sessionManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return _sessionManager;
}

@end
```

I wrote several classes that extend this `SessionManager`. One for every entity in the API: `RestaurantManager`, `StreetManager` and `AreaManager`. What happens, though, is that when I use one of them and then another, it will still use the first one.

```
NSArray *restaurants = [[RestaurantManager sharedManager] getRestaurants];

// restaurants contains all the restaurants

NSArray *streets = [[StreetsManager sharedManager] getStreets];

// streets still contains all the restaurants
```

Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Comment: As long as you don't override the class method the subclasses use always the same shared instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `+ (id)sharedManager` methods in subclasses. Otherwise, they go to the same `sharedManager` method and interact with the same `static SessionManager` variable.